# Avalonia style selector doen't works on derived classes

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm having an issue to style my custom control derived from button.

I inherited the Button class to add a DependencyProperty to it:

```
public class IconButton : Button, IStyleable
{
    Type IStyleable.StyleKey => typeof(Button);

    public static readonly StyledProperty<string> IconProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.Register<IconButton, string>(nameof(Icon));

    public string Icon
    {
        get { return GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a style targetting only this derived class:

```xml
    <Styles xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:i="clr-namespace:Projektanker.Icons.Avalonia;assembly=Projektanker.Icons.Avalonia"
            xmlns:cc="*****.*****.CustomControls">
        <Design.PreviewWith>
            <Border Padding="20">
              <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <cc:IconButton Content="hello custom" Icon="fab fa-github"/>
                <Button Content="hello"/>
              </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Design.PreviewWith>
    
      <Style Selector=":is(cc|IconButton)">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <i:Icon Value="{TemplateBinding Icon}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
              </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </Styles>
```

[image]

AS you can see, the content is not my control template as the icon is not visible and the background is not red. Therefore I can't use my dependencyproperty.

Any suggestions or is it not supported by the language?
I read on the documentation that is(****) for selector is intended to support derived type so I would expect my code to be working :(

Thx for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove IStyleable and your overriden StyleKey. You are telling the selector that it should look for a Button style and not your style.

Happy coding
Tim

PS I cannot test it on my own right now, so if it doesn't work please tell me here.

---

Update: I just made a blank new project and tested your code. Once I remove the `StyleKey`, it works:

[image]

This is the modified `IconButton`:

```cs
public class IconButton : Button
{
    public static readonly StyledProperty<string> IconProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.Register<IconButton, string>(nameof(Icon));
    
    public string Icon
    {
        get { return GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

If you are able to upload a minimal sample on Github, I can have a look what may be wrong.

---

Update 2: Looking into your demo App I see that you use a third party icon lib. The lib requires you to configure a special service at start up, see: https://github.com/Projektanker/Icons.Avalonia#1-register-icon-providers-on-app-start-up

I send you a PR which fixes your issue.

[image]

Happy coding
Tim

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do this otherwise the component doesn't render at all. You need to implement IStyleable in order to get your inherited component rendered :x
Also I tried to return the type of my class instead of typeof(Buttton) but it seems like avalonia doesn't succeed getting the base class style if I do this and the component doesn't render either !

Comment: You also need to add your Syle via StyleInclude in App.axaml

Comment: Yeah sure, it has been done. But anyway, the Design.PreviewWith render the style directly within the style file and doesn't require any includes whatsoever.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please double-check. Thx.

Comment: I will try this our again and upload my code sample if it doesn't work, thx for the answers

Comment: Here is sample code not working for me : https://github.com/Ehrode/TestIconButton

The file with the style and a button for the test is here:
https://github.com/Ehrode/TestIconButton/blob/main/TestCustomControl/Assets/IconButton.axaml

Comment: Ah yea, I configured it into my main project, just forgot to add it in the sample one! But indeed, in the sample project, after configuring the service it works. But I'm pretty sure I still had an issue in the main project with the service configured and the same code. I will try it out again and mark the thread as resolved if it works, thanks for your hep!

Comment: Ok it works, I dunno what I was doing wrong the first time I tried removing the style key! Thanks a lot for your time!